# Title of legend produced by stat_binhex

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a two-dimensional scatter plot:

```
DF = data.frame(x=rnorm(1000),y=rnorm(1000))
```

I plotted them with ggplot2, and stat_binhex()

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  stat_binhex()
```

I want to change the title of the legend.

I've tried `+ guides(fill = "Point intensity")` or `+ guides(color = "Point intensity")`, but it's not having it.

I don't think I can use `scale_colour_continuous` because `stat_binhex` creates the colour palette.

Any help?

Comment: Use `labs(fill = ...)` to change the title.

Comment: You can also use `scale_fill_continuous(name = "New Legend Title")`.